# Show that discrete System is stable

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, stability-theory

I have a system given that is described by
$$x_{k+1} = Ax_k$$
with vectors $x$ and a Matrix $A$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$. I would like to show that the system is stable and tried to proof that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}A^n = 0.$$ Or equivalent that $\lVert A \rVert < 1$. Is this sufficient to proof that this system is stable? The question is meant in general for discrete system, hence I have no number examples.

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient. Just show that all eigenvalues are inside the unit circle.

Comment: And eigenvalues are inside the unit circle is equivalent to the fact that ||A|| < 1, because the eigenvalues are $\le ||A||$, right?

Comment: Yes, if $\|A\|$ is an induced (spectral) norm

Comment: So using the Frobenius norm is not sufficient?

Comment: Works as well since $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F$